# Catching a swig template error correctly when using res.render on Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm using Express.js and swig templates to build a web application. The problem is that when the swig rendering fails (for instance when the template is faulty), I can't catch the error which it throws and node crashes.

Specifically, the error comes when I use the stringGenerator function to return an object and reference the object the wrong way. I get an 'Unexpected key' error thrown which I can't seem to catch.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   try {
       res.render('index', { 'stringFunction': stringGenerator });
   } catch(err) {
     console.error(err);
   }
});
```

How do I catch the error which swig throws at res.render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use [`express-domain-middleware`](https://npmjs.org/package/express-domain-middleware). That allows you to catch errors in routes and deal with them with a normal Express error handler:

```
app.use(require('express-domain-middleware'));

...your routes...

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error('An error occurred:', err.message);
  res.send(500);
});
```

This doesn't strictly deal with Swig errors only though, but I haven't found another way besides using domains to catch Swig errors.

Comment: This answer seems to work well! Although I was hoping for a solution where the error could be catched in a more precise manner...

Comment: @villetou I agree. The only way I see how is to check `err.stack` in the error handler to see if the error was thrown somewhere in the Swig module.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Swig ~1.2.2 it will pass the exception to Express which will handle it in whatever error handler you have setup.